# Get next month first date based on datetime numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Data**

```
lst=array(['2019-08-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-09-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-10-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-11-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-02-28T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

**Goal**

I want to get next month first date for each element in the above array. For example, `2019-08-30T00:00:00.000000000` will be `'2019-09-01T00:00:00.000000000'`,`2020-01-23T00:00:00.000000000` will be 
`2020-02-01T00:00:00.000000000`,the final ouput will be dictionary like `{'2019-08-30T00:00:00.000000000':'2019-09-01T00:00:00.000000000',……}`

**Try**

It's easy to get by `+timedelta(days=1)` for some elements, but it's hard for  `'2020-01-23T00:00:00.000000000'` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to month units, add one and convert back:

```
(lst.astype("M8[M]")+1).astype("M8[ns]")
# array(['2019-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-10-01T00:00:00.000000000',
#        '2019-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-12-01T00:00:00.000000000',
#        '2020-02-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
#       dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```